# Merging rows in a single table shows duplicate result

Tags: mysql

I am working on a simple PHP and MySQL project where it has a check-in and check-out feature.

I am having a little problem with merging rows in a single table. Below is the raw data that you can see without merging on rows.

> ```
> mysql> SELECT * FROM clock;
> +--------+---------+---------------------+----------+
> | log_id | user_id | xtimestamp           | text     |
> +--------+---------+---------------------+----------+
> |      1 | 1000     | 2012-05-10 07:47:06 | CHECKIN  |
> |      2 | 1003     | 2012-05-10 07:47:23 | CHECKIN  |
> |      3 | 1002     | 2012-05-10 07:47:36 | CHECKIN  |
> |      4 | 1002     | 2012-05-10 07:47:49 | CHECKOUT |
> |      5 | 1003     | 2012-05-10 07:48:11 | CHECKOUT |
> |      6 | 1000     | 2012-05-10 07:48:23 | CHECKOUT |
> |      7 | 1000     | 2012-05-10 07:48:52 | CHECKIN  |
> +--------+---------+---------------------+----------+
> ```

Here's my SQL query to merge rows on a single table to have a check-in and check-out view.

```
SELECT a.log_id as 'ID'
 , a.user_id as 'User_ID'
 , a.xtimestamp as 'CHECKIN'
 , b.xtimestamp as 'CHECKOUT' 
FROM clock a, clock b 
WHERE a.info = 'CHECKIN' 
AND b.info = 'CHECKOUT' 
AND a.user_id = b.user_id 
GROUP BY a.log_id;
```

And here's the result of the query.

```
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ID | User_ID | CHECKIN             | CHECKOUT            |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 1000    | 2012-05-10 07:47:06 | 2012-05-10 07:48:23 |
|  2 | 1003    | 2012-05-10 07:47:23 | 2012-05-10 07:48:11 |
|  3 | 1002    | 2012-05-10 07:47:36 | 2012-05-10 07:47:49 |
|  7 | 1000    | 2012-05-10 07:48:52 | 2012-05-10 07:48:23 |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

As you can see on the result above, there are 4 records return but it should be 3 because on ID 7 with user_id 1000 there is no CHECKOUT record yet, id 1 and id 7 has the same CHECKOUT date.

What I want to achieve is something like this

```
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ID | User_ID | CHECKIN             | CHECKOUT            |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 1000    | 2012-05-10 07:47:06 | 2012-05-10 07:48:23 |
|  2 | 1003    | 2012-05-10 07:47:23 | 2012-05-10 07:48:11 |
|  3 | 1002    | 2012-05-10 07:47:36 | 2012-05-10 07:47:49 |
|  7 | 1000    | 2012-05-10 07:48:52 | null                |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

or like this

```
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ID | User_ID | CHECKIN             | CHECKOUT            |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 1000    | 2012-05-10 07:47:06 | 2012-05-10 07:48:23 |
|  2 | 1003    | 2012-05-10 07:47:23 | 2012-05-10 07:48:11 |
|  3 | 1002    | 2012-05-10 07:47:36 | 2012-05-10 07:47:49 |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

If anyone has a great idea, please share.. thanks a lot.

Comment: The `log_id` values shown in your table at the start of your question don't reconcile with the outputs shown elsewhere; whilst I don't think this impairs understanding of your problem, you might like to edit your question so that it's consistent?

Comment: @eggyal, you got a point and you gave me idea and log_id is the culprit. I have updated my SQL and it works now.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer. You'll then be able to accept it after a certain time has passed.

Comment: @llion thanks also for idea. I tried to post the solution as answer but i am not allowed yet until 7 hours so I edited my questions instead with answer.

Comment: Your proposed solution is unreliable.  According to the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html):  "*The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate*" - therefore your query might obtain any check in/out for each user, not necessarily the most recent.

Comment: @eggyal thanks for the advised. So in this kind of scenario, what is the most effective and error free SQL query?

Comment: If Arion's answer does what you need, then that's the way to go.

Comment: @eggyal upon reviewing my query and Arion's query, it seems like other results won't showed up if they have the same user_id, it is because it was group by user_id?

Comment: @user1249125: Correct. If you want to show every check in/out for every user, you'll need to use a different approach.

Comment: @eggyal need your expertise now, my query and Arions query doesn't show up records with the same user_id.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11092/discussion-between-user1249125-and-eggyal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   check_in.log_id           AS `CHECKIN ID`
  ,      check_in.user_id          AS `User_ID`
  ,      check_in.xtimestamp       AS `CHECKIN`
  ,      MIN(check_out.xtimestamp) AS `CHECKOUT` 
FROM     clock                     AS `check_in`
  JOIN   clock                     AS `check_out`
      ON (
           check_out.info = 'CHECKOUT'
       AND  check_in.info = 'CHECKIN'
       AND  check_in.user_id     = check_out.user_id
       AND  check_in.xtimestamp <= check_out.xtimestamp
      )
GROUP BY check_in.log_id, check_in.user_id, check_in.xtimestamp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    MIN(CASE WHEN info='CHECKIN'  THEN xtimestamp ELSE NULL END) AS CHECKIN,
    MAX(CASE WHEN info='CHECKOUT'  THEN xtimestamp ELSE NULL END) AS CHECKOUT,
    MAX(log_id) AS ID,
    User_ID
FROM
    clock
GROUP BY
    User_ID
```